# Unable to open port

Tags: iptables, firewall

I try to convince apache to listen to two ports (80 and 8091). That works perfectly locally.

I configured `iptables` so that port 8091 is shown as follows using `iptables` -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:8091
```

and expected that I can reach the port/web page from outside, which does not work.

When I use `nmap -p 80,8091 -v -sV` with the external ip-address from the server itself (locally) it looks as expected

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
80/tcp   open  http    Apache httpd 2.4.29 ((Ubuntu))
8091/tcp open  http    Apache httpd 2.4.29 ((Ubuntu))
```

When I do the same call from a remote machine `nmap` returns

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE VERSION
80/tcp   open     http    Apache httpd 2.4.29 ((Ubuntu))
8091/tcp filtered jamlink
```

and I cannot reach the web page on 8091, which as mentioned above is perfectly reachable locally using the external address. Has anyone any idea what might be wrong here.

Comment: Does 'remote machine' mean on the same LAN? Or across the internet? Try on the same LAN first.

Comment: If you mean 'remote' as in outside your network, then you need to make sure you're port-forwarding 8091 properly to the internal machine.  If this is a VPS, then you need to make sure there's no additional firewall mechanism in play (Digital Ocean and AWS have those in play for extra security)

Comment: @user535733 it is a rented server outside of the LAN, i.e. across the internet.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thank's for the hint. I will try to clarify it with the provider of the rented server.

Comment: The hint from ThomasWard solved the problem. Many thanks. There was an additional firewall in place.

Comment: @tww59 I've converted the comment into an answer.  Feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some VPS providers, there are extra firewalls in play to protect the systems.

This is the case with Google Cloud, Azure Cloud, VMware Cloud, DigitalOcean, AWS, and others.

Make sure that there's no additional firewall in play, and if there is add the port into the allowed list on the firewall.